# Pass variable into Batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a script that works that requires me to pass variable to batch file, test.bat

**script**

```
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["test.bat",  userIP],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

**batch file**

```
@echo off

D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe -l -x $1
```

It is not working. If I invoke the script with userIP it return blank output.

But if I do not use batch file and replace

```
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["test.bat",  userIP],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

with

```
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x",  userIP],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

then it works perfectly. If I invoke with userIP it returns the current user.

How to fix this?

Comment: How is it not working? What error do you get?

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path to `test.bat`?

Comment: If you'd tested starting your `test.bat` by hand, you'd have saved yourself a lot of trouble figuring out if Python was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Windows batch file, not a POSIX.2-compatible shell,

```
D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe -l -x $1
```

should be

```
D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe -l -x %1
```

(By the way, if it *were* a POSIX-compatible shell, you'd need to quote, as in `-x "$1"`, to ensure that your parameter were passed through correctly).